# Как записать строку жирным в файл word?

Tags: python, ms-word

Есть строка. Возможно нужно добавить какие-то специальные символы для того, чтобы ms word понял, что строка должна быть жирным. Какие это символы? Или может нужно подключить какие то библиотеки?

Comment: я ничего не понял, как python понимает что это ms word, как ms word понимает что это строка?
Какие библиотеки используются? Какой тип файла (doc, docx, odt  и тд)?

Comment: в python формируется строка с текстом. Часть этой строки должна быть выделена. далее это строка записывается в текстовый файл. При просмотре этого файла в word 2007 часть строки должна быть жирной. Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 3):

Как известно, docx-формат это хранящийся в zip-контейнере xml.

Пример разметки жирного текста в ./word/document.xml (находится внутри file.docx.zip)

```
<w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:b/> // метка жирного текста
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Жирный текст</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Answer (score 2):

Это вам в сторону формама docx смотреть надо. А спецификации этого формата занимают более 6000 страниц ;D
Ну, если делать по уму. Если хотите по-быстрому, можете написать пример текста, выделить часть текста в нем, сохранить получившийся документ в файл. Далее, этот файл распаковать любым архиватором, который понимает формат zip(docx - по сути, набор xml файлов, упакованных в zip). Далее, открываете файл document.xml, и ужасаетесь)) Далее, набираетесь терпения, пытаетесь разобраться, что там к чему, и делаете шаблон, на основании которого сможете потом писать текст жирным. 
Но это очень некрасивый вариант.

А еще Я нашел для python [библиотечку](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx), которая обещает быть интересной. А если не подошло, то [попробуйте это](http://goo.gl/DAR5U)

Comment: Запугаете девушку, садисты. @Ольга Можно выводить в html (добавить нужные теги при выводе в файл), word'ы html понимают. А там можно задать и <strong>слово</strong>. Но тогда в начале будет <html> и далее по порядку.

Comment: тоже некрасивый вариант))

Comment: Лучший из вариантов, docx удобный формат с ним можно потом много где работать, да и библиотека на первый взгляд интересная.

Comment: Можно в RTF выводить, word его понимает.

Comment: Ви таки когда-нибудь RTF формировали (мне -- приходилось). И зачем?

Comment: @alexlz, нет. 

Единственное, что я про него знал, что он текстовый. 

Но благодаря Вашему комментарию (кстати, большое спасибо!)  я его больше никому рекомендовать не буду.

Набил пару строк и посмотрел на результат. Лучше уж html.

Comment: docx - это тоже убийство, Я уже четвертый день ломаю мозги, Как таблицы многостраничные красивые в нем печатать. На ум приходит только тупо создание шаблонов. Форматирование там - та еще е*ань

Comment: Да вы гоните. `.DOCX` файл это ZIP-архив с кучей xml файлов. Это ж надо сначала найти файл, в котором основной текст лежит, а прежде ещё и распаковать его. Проще все же воспользоваться `.RTF` с его форматированием. Главное не забывать закрывать формат

Comment: А может и в самом деле RTF? [Вот ссылка](http://pyrtf.sourceforge.net/)

    PyRTF is a set of python classes that make it possible to produce RTF documents from python programs. The library has no external dependancies and in my ...

Answer (score 2):

Для такой простой задачи я бы посоветовал использовать [готовое решение](http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/examples.html).

Смысл в том, что файл `docx` изменяет `LibreOffice`, а Вы обращаетесь в нему через `api`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать библиотеку [docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Например, следующий код сохранит строку "Something" жирным в файле test.docx

Это мы применяем только к одному параграфу, который хранится в переменной `p`

```
import docx

s = "Something"
doc = docx.Document()
p = doc.add_paragraph()

runner = p.add_run(s)
runner.bold = True

doc.save('test.docx')
```